# Unknow php error in sql INSERT INTO

Tags: php, oop, registration

I have problem in my registration.
Look on my code:

```
//player.php
<?php
session_start();
class Player
{
var $name;
function _construct($name)
{
    $this->$name = $name;
}
function CreatePlayer($name, $pass, $mail, $date, $type)
{
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost","wewewe", "wewewe");
        if(!$con)
        {
            die( $return = mysql_error());
        }   
        mysql_select_db("wewewe", $con);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS (name, pass, mail, date, type) VALUES ('$name', '$pass', '$mail', '$date','$type')");
        mysql_close(link);
    }
    return $return;
}
function LoginPlayer($name, $pass)
{

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","username", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("con", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM USERS WHERE pass='$pass' AND name='$name'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
    }
    mysql_close($link);
}
}
?>
//reg.php
<html>
<form action="log.php" method="post">
Meno: <input type="text" name="meno">
<br>
Heslo: <input type="text" name="heslo">
<br>
Mail: <input type="text" name="mail">
<br>
Date: <input type="text" name="date">
<br>
Type: <input type="text" name="type">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<br>
</form>
<?php

include 'player.php';
$name = $_POST['meno'];
$pass = $_POST['heslo'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$obj = new Player($name);

$res = $obj->CreatePlayer($name, $pass, $mail, $date, $type);
if($res==true)
{
echo "jo!";
}
else
{
echo $res;
}
?>
```

My problem is that if I write text to all fields and press ok, my page will restart but without any error message. And when I will look to a database, theres nothing. Why? Can anybody plese help me?

EDIT:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 class Player
 {
var $name;
function _construct($name)
{
    $this->$name = $name;
}
function CreatePlayer($name, $pass, $mail, $date, $type)
{
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","wewewe", "wewewe");
        if(!$con)
        {
            die( $return = mysql_error());
        }   
        mysql_select_db("wewewe", $con);
        $query = "INSERT INTO USERS (name, pass, mail, date, type) VALUES ('$name', '$pass', '$mail', '$date','$type')";

        $retrn = var_dump($query); // SHOWS YOU QUERY STRING

        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // EXECUTES QUERY OR THROWS EXCEPTON (SHOWS ERROR TOO)
        mysql_close($con);
    }
    return $return;
}
function LoginPlayer($name, $pass)
{

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","username", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("con", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM USERS WHERE pass='$pass' AND name='$name'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
    }
    mysql_close($link);
}
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: use ´$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());´
meaning add or die(mysql_error()); to all ur queries
to get the errors when uve to them post it and ill help u out

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injections. i suggest brushing up on database fundamentals.

Comment: But if it is in Class, I have to return error. Or not?

Comment: can you post your sql query. `echo "SELECT FROM USERS WHERE pass='$pass' AND name= ... "`

Comment: This is off-topic but use prepared statements when you deal with form input at all costs. And also in the construct you probably want to do $this->name instead of $this->$name

Comment: Oh guys i'm puzzled. Now, it works. Without any error message it works. I'm placing code to the edit, please help me to find place where was the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think its not going inside `if($_POST['submit'])`

change

```
<input type="submit">
```

to

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
```

Comment: You are welcome. Can you see any error now? Do you have display_error enabled?

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="submit">` modify to `<input type="submit" name="submit">`

To debug SQL INSERTING :

```
mysql_select_db("wewewe", $con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS (name, pass, mail, date, type) VALUES ('$name', '$pass', '$mail', '$date','$type')");
mysql_close(link);
```

modify to

```
mysql_select_db("wewewe", $con);
$query = "INSERT INTO USERS (name, pass, mail, date, type) VALUES ('$name', '$pass', '$mail', '$date','$type')";

var_dump($query); // SHOWS YOU QUERY STRING

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // EXECUTES QUERY OR THROWS EXCEPTON (SHOWS ERROR TOO)
mysql_close(link);
```

Comment: show us your query string. Also you can try $query_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); var_dump($query_result); So you can see if the query execution succeed

Answer (score 0):

Your query in the function LoginPlayer is incorrect. You may simply fix it like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM USERS WHERE pass='$pass' AND name='$name'");
```

Comment: As you can see in re.php, i'm not using function LoginPlayer.